# Change the search placeholder by code

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchbar, placeholder

I'm trying to change the search placeholder to "Search for a device" in table view by using this code in viewDidLoad:

```
  let placeholderAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)]
        let attributedPlaceholder: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Search for a Device", attributes: placeholderAttributes)
        let textFieldPlaceHolder = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
        textFieldPlaceHolder?.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
```

I'm sure everything is OK in the code, but why the placeholder is not changing?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, try to remove the snippet into your `viewDidLoad` instead.

Comment: I ment that you should place all your code in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Are you setting the placeholder somewhere else? Maybe in the storyboard too?

Comment: Hard to tell why it´s not working.. Can you share your code and I´ll try to help you further.